# Proper way to extend Python Queue?

Tags: python, queue

I'm writing a custom sub-class of Queue.Queue and run into a situation where I need to acquire a queue-level lock when my custom `put()` is being called.  I'd like to reuse the existing lock Queue has (`Queue.mutex`), but can't because its not an `RLock`.

In the source (python 2.6), it says:

```
# Override these methods [_put, _get, etc] to implement other queue organizations
# (e.g. stack or priority queue).
# These will only be called with appropriate locks held
```

But the online documentation doesn't mention overriding them.  The other Queue implementations in that module override these.  So, I'm kinda inclined to believe that the `_put` method is package-private and isn't really intended for use outside the Queue module.

Does anyone know how kosher it would be to use `Queue._put` and friends in my own subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, it would be completely kosher. In Python, [the source *is* the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147704/reference-manual-for-python/8147761#8147761), or at least should be considered as a supplement to the published API documentation. This is largely a consequence of the enforced use of whitespace and coding conventions that [emphasize clear, readable code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): when you have questions that the documentation doesn't answer, you're *supposed* to be able to go to the source code and look up the answers.

In particular, details like this one are irrelevant to most clients of the `Queue` module (who are simply *using* the classes), so they wouldn't make it into the published docs. But if you want to subclass `Queue`, the developers expect you to be digging deeper, so the note is there in the source code for you to find.

I will also mention that Python doesn't really have a concept of "package-private." Semantically, there's no difference between a subclass which is in the same module and one which is in a different module, even one you write yourself. In fact, Python doesn't even have a concept of "private". Instead, it relies on a principle of responsible usage: as a developer you're expected to be smart enough not to use internal methods when you don't need to. Starting a member name with an underscore is simply a clue that it's an internal method, and that you probably shouldn't be accessing it if you are simply *using* the class - but if you're subclassing it, anything is fair game.

Comment: Do you have a more authoritative source than your own answer for "the source is the documentation"?  I've seen various discussions on python-dev about what visibility one should assume from the stdlib when there's no official documentation.  Another point I hadn't considered is that Queue is essentially the same in 3.2, so I don't have to worry about upgrade issues.

Comment: No I don't, it's just a sense I've picked up over a few years of programming with Python. In any case I didn't intended that link to be a source or to have any sort of authority; I just wanted to work it in somewhere since I remembered writing that answer recently and I thought it would be interesting further reading.

Comment: Actually: I think I may have read _somewhere_ more authoritative that the source should be considered a supplement to the documentation, or something to that effect. But I don't remember any details.